# Slowly rising entire function

Tags: calculus, analysis

Is it possible to find slowly rising entire function (possibly elementary) which is real on real axis? All my trials failed.

$ x \in \mathbb{R} \implies f(x) \in \mathbb{R},
\quad
x \in \mathbb{R} : \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{f(x)}{\ln(x)} \to 1,
\quad
\text{or}
\quad
x \in \mathbb{R}, n \in \mathbb{N}_{+} : \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{f(x)}{\sqrt[n]{x}} \to 1$

Comment: Do you mean an increasing function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ with one of those properties?

Comment: Well, increasing at $+\infty$, if it does "something special" near the origin I do not care. And yes, one of the two properties ("or"). These are just examples, I think in general about a function rising more slowly than $x$.

Comment: The reciprocal of the gamma function grows quite slowly (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_gamma_function).

Comment: I think we should stick to the two examples I provided. $1/\Gamma$ goes to zero. I want a rise to infinity.

Comment: Maybe the following approximation theorem is useful: Let $g \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $\varepsilon > 0$. Then there exists an entire function $f$ such that $|f(x)-g(x)|< \varepsilon$ $(x \in  \mathbb{R})$. See Gaier D.: Lectures on Complex Approximation (1987), Chapter 4, Theorem 3. This at least shows that entire functions with the desired property exist.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I read over this. Maybe you can construct one using the wikipedia entry under "Growth"? 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function

Comment: Gerd 2/3: This looks like the correct answer, maybe you should post it. Pity there is no example. Yet, does the theorem you cite say, that $f(x)$ takes real values on the real axis?

Comment: @F.Jatpil I overlooked $f(\mathbb{R}) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. In fact these approximation theorems do not say that the entire function is real on the real axis.

Comment: I now found a version that works. I will post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a type of approximation theorems that allow to approximate certain functions $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{C}$ by entire functions on the real axis. The originally result in this direction seems so be Carleman's Theorem:

Theorem (Carleman, 1927): Let $g \in C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C})$ and let $\varepsilon \in C(\mathbb{R},(0,\infty))$. Then there exists an entire function $f$ such that
$$
\forall x \in \mathbb{R}: ~ |f(x)-g(x)|<  \varepsilon(x).
$$
Unfortunately this originally result does not say that we can have $f(\mathbb{R}) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ if $g(\mathbb{R}) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. The proof I found in the book of Dieter Gaier: Lectures on Complex Approximation, Birkhäuser (1987), $§$3 Theorem 1 relies on Runge's Theorem and I don't see if this proof would give this property. However there is a different proof of Carleman's Theorem by L. Hoischen: A note on the approximation of continuous functions by integral functions, Journal London Math. Soc. 42 (1967), p.351-354 which shows that $f$ can be chosen real valued on $\mathbb{R}$ if $g$ is real valued (which is expressly mentioned there). With this version we get the existence of entire functions with the desired properties.

For example by choosing $g(x)=0$ $(x \le 1)$, $g(x)=\ln(x)$ $(x > 1)$ and constant $\varepsilon =1$ there is a function $f \in H(\mathbb{C})$ such that $f(x)\in \mathbb{R}$ $(x \in \mathbb{R})$ and
$|f(x)-\ln(x)| < 1$ $(x> 1)$, so $f(x)/\ln(x) \to 1$ $(x\to \infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is wrong due to my misinterpretation of the word 'entire'.

---

**Wrong answer**

$$f=\begin{cases}\ln(x)\quad x\geq1\\ x-1\quad x\leq1\end{cases}$$

This function obviously satisfies the condition $\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{f(x)}{\ln x}=1$. It is also increasing, bijective, continuous, and differentiable.

Comment: Entire functions are infinitely differentiable.

Comment: But it is not entire (see behavior at $x=1$). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function

Comment: @F.Jatpil Ah, I see, I thought the word entire meant defined on the entirety of $\Bbb R$. Thanks a lot!